# backtrack 5r3 pyrit does not detect nvidia card

Tags: laptop, nvidia-geforce, backtrack, optimus

I tried to use pyrit on live dvd backtrack 5r3 with my Nvidia GT540M gt of my laptop Dell XPS 15 L502x.

Pyrit couldn't detect the nvidia card, it only detected the 4 CPU cores.

Is this due to Optimus ? and how can I handle this ?

Thanks

```
root@bt:/opt# pyrit benchmark
Pyrit 0.4.0 (C) 2008-2011 Lukas Lueg http://pyrit.googlecode.com
This code is distributed under the GNU General Public License v3+

Running benchmark (1499.3 PMKs/s)... / 

Computed 1499.26 PMKs/s total.
#1: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 393.4 PMKs/s (RTT 3.2)
#2: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 407.1 PMKs/s (RTT 3.0)
#3: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 381.8 PMKs/s (RTT 3.1)
#4: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 385.2 PMKs/s (RTT 3.1)

root@bt:~/Desktop# pyrit list_cores
Pyrit 0.4.0 (C) 2008-2011 Lukas Lueg http://pyrit.googlecode.com
This code is distributed under the GNU General Public License v3+

The following cores seem available...
#1:  'CPU-Core (SSE2)'
#2:  'CPU-Core (SSE2)'
#3:  'CPU-Core (SSE2)'
#4:  'CPU-Core (SSE2)'
```

Comment: Have you tried to install the correct nouveau driver for this card?

Comment: no, because i'm working with live dvd. so i need to know if it's not a driver's issue